# Python np.append does not work on dictionary value which is of type numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a function which given two numpy array converts them into a dictionay as follows

```
def seggregate_based_on_y(X,y):
    dictionary={}
    for index in range(len(y)):
        if y[index] in dictionary.keys():
            np.append(dictionary[y[index]],X[index])
        else:
            dictionary[y[index]]=np.array([X[index]])
    return dictionary
```

for the following input

```
X=np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]])
y=np.array([2,3,2,3,4])
d=seggregate_based_on_y(X,y)
print(d)
```

I expect 'd' to be `{2: array([[1, 1],[3,3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],[4,4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}` but I get 'd' to be `{2: array([[1, 1]]), 3: array([[2, 2]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}` that is the if statement is not working. What should be done?

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html `append()` returns a copy of the array it doesn’t work in place.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for pointing out, I did not know that. But the problem still remains, do you know if there is any way I can have above result as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, like the comments say, you have to assign your dictionary the new value. See the below fix:

```
def seggregate_based_on_y(X,y):
    dictionary={}
    for index in range(len(y)):
        if y[index] in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[y[index]] = np.append(dictionary[y[index]],X[index])
        else:
            dictionary[y[index]]=np.array([X[index]])
    return dictionary
```

With the given data it outputs:

```
{2: array([1, 1, 3, 3]), 3: array([2, 2, 4, 4]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}
```

This is not the same as your expected results because `np.append` will append to the same vector. To get the required output use `np.vstack`

```
def seggregate_based_on_y(X,y):
    dictionary={}
    for index in range(len(y)):
        if y[index] in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[y[index]] = np.vstack((dictionary[y[index]],X[index]))
        else:
            dictionary[y[index]]=np.array([X[index]])
    return dictionary
```

the output here is:

```
{2: array([[1, 1],
       [3, 3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],
       [4, 4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you may use the built-in function `zip`:

```
def seggregate_based_on_y(X,y):
    d = {}
    for k, v in zip(y, X):
        if k in d:
            d[k] = np.append(d[k], v.reshape(1, 2), axis=0)
        else:
            d[k] = v.reshape(1, 2)

    return d


X=np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]])
y=np.array([2,3,2,3,4])
print(seggregate_based_on_y(X,y))
```

output:

```
{2: array([[1, 1],
        [3, 3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],
        [4, 4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
import numpy as np

def seggregate_based_on_y(X,y):
    dictionary={}
    for index in range(len(y)):
        if y[index] in dictionary.keys():
            z = np.append(dictionary[y[index]], X[index])
            dictionary[y[index]] = z.reshape(z.size // 2, 2)

        else:
            dictionary[y[index]]=np.array([X[index]])
    return dictionary

X=np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]])
y=np.array([2,3,2,3,4])
d=seggregate_based_on_y(X,y)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{2: array([[1, 1],[3, 3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],[4, 4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaultdict` does this sort of collection easily:

```
In [268]: from collections import defaultdict                                                          
In [269]: x = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]                                                          
In [270]: y = [2,3,2,3,4]                                                                              
In [271]: dd = defaultdict(list)                                                                       
In [272]: for i,j in zip(y, x): 
     ...:     dd[i].append(j) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [273]: dd                                                                                           
Out[273]: defaultdict(list, {2: [[1, 1], [3, 3]], 3: [[2, 2], [4, 4]], 4: [[5, 5]]})
```

If the result must be array instead of list, it can be transformed with:

```
In [274]: d = {k: np.array(dd[k]) for k in dd}                                                         
In [275]: d                                                                                            
Out[275]: 
{2: array([[1, 1],
        [3, 3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],
        [4, 4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])}
```

List append is faster than `np.append` (or any of the `numpy` `concatenate` family of functions).  List append operates in-place.

`defaultdict` could build an array directly (but I expect this to be slower):

```
In [280]: dd = defaultdict(lambda:np.zeros((0,2),int))                                                 
In [281]: for i,j in zip(y, x): 
     ...:     dd[i] = np.vstack((dd[i],j)) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [282]: dd                                                                                           
Out[282]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>, {2: array([[1, 1],
                    [3, 3]]), 3: array([[2, 2],
                    [4, 4]]), 4: array([[5, 5]])})
```